# Adding multiple rows to sharepoint list from excel - contains person objects

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list that contain columns of the type "person or group", and I have an excel file of rows I want to add to the SharePoint list. Normally with other SharePoint lists, I can simply go into the "grid view" mode on the list and paste all the excel rows in. However, this method is not working for the columns of type "person or group". Is there another way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering email id in the Excel column. It will import fine into the Person or Group field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).